# Variable definition not found in the robot framework

Tags: variables, selenium, pycharm, robotframework

My Code in the robot-file:

```
${myVar}=    Set Variable    ${30.0}
```

looks like this in PyCharm:

[image]

When I hover my mouse over the float value I get the error: Variable definition not found.

Can somebody explain why this happens?

Answer (score 3):

The explanation is that it's a bug in PyCharm's robotframework mode. The code is perfectly legal robotframework syntax.

Though, one could argue that it's not a bug and that the tooltip is telling the truth: there really is no variable named `${30.0}`. What it doesn't say is that, even though there is no variable named `${30.0}`, the syntax is perfectly valid.